# Sqlite: select, grouping according to one attribute desc. and sorting according to another asc

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting, group-by

What is the best way to group according to an attribute in descending order, but sort according to another in ascending order.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
logs  (id INTEGER NOT NULL,
       prompt INTEGER NOT NULL,
       value TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (id));

INSERT INTO logs(id, prompt, value) VALUES(1, 10, "a");
INSERT INTO logs(id, prompt, value) VALUES(2,  4, "a");
INSERT INTO logs(id, prompt, value) VALUES(3, 10, "b");
INSERT INTO logs(id, prompt, value) VALUES(4,  6, "c");
INSERT INTO logs(id, prompt, value) VALUES(5,  5, "c");
INSERT INTO logs(id, prompt, value) VALUES(6,  4, "d");
INSERT INTO logs(id, prompt, value) VALUES(7,  4, "e");
INSERT INTO logs(id, prompt, value) VALUES(8, 10, "a");
INSERT INTO logs(id, prompt, value) VALUES(9, 10, "z");
```

Now, I would like a request that is going to:

1. group according to **prompt** (only one row per distinct prompt)
2. keep only the **value** of the row with largest **id**
3. sort by ascending **id** (which I don't need to keep)

So for here I need

```
prompt | value
   10  |  "z"
    4  |  "e"
    6  |  "c"
    5  |  "c"
```

How is this possible? And how it can be made not too inefficient? And can you avoid an intermediate request (i.e., select from a select - which I feel might the way to do it, but not sure how).

**UPDATE:** The best I was able to come up with is doing an intermediate query and using the MIN operator:

```
SELECT MIN(id), prompt, lvalue
FROM logs
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT prompt as lprompt, value as lvalue
     FROM logs
     GROUP BY prompt ORDER BY id DESC)
ON
  prompt = lprompt
GROUP BY prompt ORDER BY id ASC;
```

It works but I can't help but feel this is a bad solution.

**UPDATE 2:** I wanted to clarify that I want the *first* id with which a prompt appears, and the *last* value with which it appears; and then the whole sorting in ascending order of the first ids.

```
id  |prompt | value
 1  |   10  |  "z"
 2  |    4  |  "e"
 4  |    6  |  "c"
 5  |    5  |  "c"
```

Comment: I was hoping for something better, which is why I asked the question in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
select minid, lprompt, lvalue from
(SELECT prompt as lprompt, value as lvalue, min(id) as minid, max(id) as maxid
 FROM logs
 GROUP BY prompt ORDER BY id DESC) sq
order by minid
```

[SQLFiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cac0b/4)

Comment: selecting a column not in your `group by` (`value` in this case), and trying to influence which value from the group is selected via an `order by` is a common mistake because it appears to work even though the db is free to return any value from the group. i.e. you can't force it to return the value associated with the largest id by doing an `order by id desc`. "...  arbitrarily chosen row from within the group" https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset . the same applies to mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @Mark Bannister: Thank you for your answer. In the long run this is the one that worked best. Would you mind just remind me what max(id) is for?

Comment: @Jérémie: The value returned as `lvalue` from within the subquery is determined by the optimiser - without any aggregation functions (such as `min` or `max`) this would be set by the `ORDER BY` clause. The use of the `min` function alone overrides this behaviour, since the query becomes more efficient if it sorts the resultset in ascending order by `id` within `prompt`; however, by also adding a `max` function to the subquery, such optimisation is cancelled, and the order is again determined by the `ORDER BY` clause. (You can see what happens if you run the query without the `max` function).

Comment: It's worth adding that this behaviour is undocumented, and may change in different versions of the database.

Answer (score 1):

A query using not exists to select the prompt and value with the largest id

```
select prompt, value
from logs l1
where not exists (
    select 1 from logs l2
    where l2.prompt = l1.prompt
    and l2.id > l1.id
)
order by l1.id
```

or using a subquery to directly select the largest id per prompt

```
select prompt, value
from logs l1
where id = (
    select max(id) from logs l2
    where l2.prompt = l1.prompt
)
order by l1.id
```

To select the prompt value tied to the largest id and order the result by the prompt's smallest id

```
select t1.prompt, t2.value from (
  select prompt, min(id) minid, max(id) maxid
  from logs
  group by prompt
) t1 join logs t2 on t1.maxid = t2.id
order by t1.minid
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/cac0b

Comment: @Jérémie they're table aliases

Comment: thanks! However it's not quite right, I tried the first one off, and I get [ (6, c), (5, c), (4, e), (10, z) ] if I use ASC order; and [ (10, z), (4, e), (5, c), (6, c) ] if I use DESC order. But the order I want is the order of first appearance of the prompt, i.e., [ 10, 4, 6, 5 ] (notice 6 and 5 are interverted).

Comment: @Jérémie prompt 5 has id 5 whereas prompt 6 has id 4. 5 > 4 so in descending order it should be [ 10, 4, 5, 6 ]

Comment: I understand now: I think I did not explain precisely enough that I want the first ID to be kept for the order, not the last one. And my example is built in such a way that there is very little difference in the ordering using the first or last ID. Would you mind taking a look at the update I added?

Comment: Thanks for your very fast answer, it was very useful, even though I ended up accepting the other one.